# How to relate connection less link with conection oriented l2cap channel?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, bluez, l2cap

I am studying l2cap specification. Here I found that channel type connection oriented and connection less uses ACL link which is connection less to transfer packet.

Please help me to understand how connection oriented channel with connection less logical link will process data?

If it is silly question please let me know where I can clarify this doubt.